# Cakephp passing a parameter from index page

Tags: cakephp

Is it possible to pass value as a variable in the index page?

for example, "/app/User/1"

In the controller, I would want something like this

```
public function index($id = null){
...
}
```

In Cakephp, it will give an error and saying "Error: The action 1 is not defined in controller"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is because you're missing the *action* part of the url

Try **/app/users/index/1**

Note the plural on the controller part. The $id is passed to the action as you want with that.

Comment: ah.. I did put in /index/ but silly mistake is that not using plural that's why it didn't work.